# Vector constructor example with const pointer

Tags: c++

I'm reading [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry) tutorial on computer graphics, and ran across the following code example.

```
template<typename T> 
class Vec3 
{ 
public: 
    // 3 most basic ways of initializing a vector
    Vec3() : x(T(0)), y(T(0)), z(T(0)) {} 
    Vec3(const T &xx) : x(xx), y(xx), z(xx) {} 
    Vec3(T xx, T yy, T zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {} 
    T x, y, z; 
}; 

typedef Vec3<float> Vec3f; 

Vec3<float> a; 
Vec3f b;
```

I recognize that each constructor is making use of member initializer lists.

1. The default constructor initializes `x`, `y`, and `z` as `0` of type `T`
2. ?
3. The constructor accepts `x`, `y`, and `z` explicility and initializes the member variables accordingly.

I'm not sure what 2. is trying to illustrate, or how I would use it. What does `const T &xx` mean exactly? I get that `xx` is a pointer to some variable of type `T`, but is the `const` referring to the pointer itself or the variable it's pointing to? Furthermore, what's the point of initializing `x`, `y`, and `z` with the same variable?

Comment: `&` denotes a reference type, not a pointer. References can't be made to change which instance they refer to, so there is no confusion as to what `const` applies to. Note that this use of `&` is distinct from the address-of operator, which is also `&`.

Comment: The tutorial is just inconsistent when it comes to passing variables. It should have been `Vec3(T xx)`.

Comment: It’s not a very good example, in my opinion; it’s rare to want a vector with the same value for all coordinates unless that value is zero, and using a reference parameter there is completely pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const T &xx` is a reference (`&`) to a `const T`.

By using a reference instead of simply passing `T xx`, a potentially expensive copy can be avoided, in case `T` is a complex type. (Might be premature optimization in this case, because your typical `Vec3` will only be instantiated with types like `float` or `double`, but the compiler will optimize it out anyway.)

By making it a reference to a *`const`* `T`, the caller can be certain that the `T` they pass in will not be modified by the constructor. Moreover, the caller will be able to pass values that are already `const`, like literals (e.g. `Vec3<double>(1.0)`).

The rule with `const` is: it always refers to the thing that *precedes* it. So `int const *x` means that `x` is a (mutable) pointer to a `const` int, whereas `int *const x` means that `x` is a `const` pointer to a (mutable) `int`. `int const *const x` is also possible.

But what if the `const` is the first token in the type, so there's nothing that precedes it? Then it "jumps over one", so `const T &xx` is the same as `T const &xx`. For consistency, I prefer to write the latter, but many people use the former because it reads more naturally from left to right.

This constructor would be useful if you want a vector set to `(1, 1, 1)`, for instance. Of questionable mathematical meaning, but sometimes useful. For example, by multiplying a vector `(x, y, z)` by `(1, 1, 1)` we can easily compute the sum of the components of the former vector.